# Using C# to access Twitter API without browser authentication

Tags: c#, twitter, console

I am creating a C# console application which I make use to search Twitter using the API. I tried using Twitterizer however the search api with tokens doesn't work which end up with rate limiting error pretty quickly. My question is, does anyone have a code to show me how can I make a Twitter API call in C# using my consumer keys and secrets together with the access token and secrets so that the console app can run by itself without me jumping to a webpage to get a pin like most of the tutorial does? Thanks.

Regards,
Andy.

Comment: if you are using authentication then you will need to get the PIN .. that how the things work.. if you don't want that then dont use authentication and use normal search api.. but as u know you have rate limit.

Comment: no I disagree with that as when I use Twitterizer to post/update status I don't have to supply the PIN, the only thing is that the search function in Twitterizer somewhat doesn't function properly....

Comment: 1) Twitter stopped allowing basic auth a while ago. Now you need to do the oauth login which means sending user to Twitter to login, and then provide a PIN back to your app. Standard login with username/password is no longer accepted.

Comment: 2) Twitter has stopped allowing new client development. If you're making a client that duplicates what Twitter already has, the advice from Twitter is to stop development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the access token and secret, then that's all you need to call one of the methods that requires authentication.

To call any method on the Twitter API that needs authentication you need 4 items:

- Consumer Token
- Consumer Secret
- Authentication Token
- Authentication Secret

Answer (score 0):

If you check google code page for [Twitterizer](http://code.google.com/p/twitterizer/) it says:

> **Are you getting a lot of HTTP 401 error codes? Do your updates say "via Twitterizer"?**
>
> That means you've been using Twitterizer Version 1 which uses BASIC authentication. BASIC Authentication has been scheduled for removal from Twitter for months. During the month of August, the hourly limit on the number of updates that is allowable from applications using BASIC authentication is to be lowered every day. On August 31, BASIC authentication will **no longer function AT ALL**.

So you will either have to use that PIN based authentication or use usual [**Search API**](http://developer.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/public_timeline)