# C# OAuth without PIN

Tags: c#, oauth

I am trying to write a desktop application access an OAuth protect API, I have both the Consumer and Access tokens and secrets so I was wondering is there anyway to achieve this without using PIN?

Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

See my answer to [Using C# to access Twitter API without browser authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320529/using-c-to-access-twitter-api-without-browser-authentication/5321630#5321630)